# What if the processor does not have special instructions for input and output

Tags: assembly, io, cpu-architecture

I am new into assembly. This is bothering me: What if the processor does not have special instructions for input and output?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `in` and the `out` instructions of an x86 are more or less special cases of the `mov` instruction:

You *might* say that the `M//IO` pin of an 8088 CPU running in "min" mode is actually the pin `/A20`. In this case, the instruction `mov al, [si]` is used to read a byte from the address range 0-0FFFFFh and `in al, dx` is used to read a byte from the address range 100000h-10FFFFh.

The same is true for `mov [si], al` and `out dx, al`.

So an 8088 can access the address range 0-10FFFFh. And an 80386 can access and address range 0-10000FFFFh.

However, in reality, you would not talk about "address range 100000h-10FFFFh" but about the "I/O address range". But the principle is the same.

CPUs not having an `in` or `out` instruction (ARM, PowerPC, MIPS, TriCore, V850, m68k, 680x, 6502 ...) only have one address range.

All devices (keyboard, UART, mouse ...) connected to such a CPU have an address in this single address range.

For this case, these devices are accessed using the instruction that equals the x86 instruction `mov al, [si]` instead of the instruction `in al, dx` (which does not exist on such CPUs).